# Restoring from Lost+Found

Tags: data-loss

I did the most stupid thing. I was resizing the home partition with GParted and decided to cancel the process after a few minutes. Now the whole partition is in the Lost+Found folder. All folders and files are completely jumbled. It looks like the files and names are mixed up. Like you have a files under one name but when you open it, it's a completely different file or different format. I don't think I can do much about it rather than going manually through the whole bunch and see what can be still salvaged. But would appreciate any advice!